# how to make sure the link for img src from other server is secure?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have upload my animated gifs to other server, and then I link some of the img src to my html webpage. The connection shows that it is not secure in my firefox. How to I make the link become secure? Can suggest me which server is secure to upload the image and no malicious website gets our personal information.

[image: no secure connection]

Comment: I think you would need to request the image over `https://`. Not sure entirely, but when browsers say a site isn't secure, it is because they aren't using https.

Comment: side note: images are not the most harmful, but even through https, import external resources only from websites you are sure of. The content of the file could be replaced, etc. If you have a host for your webpage, always better to store your resources inside.

Comment: I follow this website to clear cookie but the images still cannot show: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-images-not-show

Comment: are you accessing your page over HTTPS?

Comment: The images cannot show, but today it can show, I don't know what happen?

Comment: neither do we...

Comment: I don't know why the server only shows me http and no https?

Comment: but when I type it https in front of the webpage, it shows me a secure connection,

Comment: @Sally_2891 The whole point of https is to give a secure connection. As long as you are requesting your images as `https://example.com/image.png` and not `http://example.com/image.png`, you should be fine.

Comment: thanks, I understood the problem now.@SamBunting